# How do I have 2 range slider that is adjusting 1 image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The two slider in html format.

```
<!--Saturation Slider-->
<input id="Hslide" type="range" min="0.0" max="2.0" value="1.0" step="0.01" oninput="showValue(value)" />

<!--Brightness Slider-->
<input id="Vslide" type="range" min="0" max="2" value="1" step="0.1" orient="vertical" oninput="showValue(value)" />
```

and the scripting,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValue(slideAmount)
{
    var pic = $('.effects').val();
    $('#pic').css('-webkit-filter', 'saturate('+slideAmount+')');
    $('#range').val(slideAmount);
    document.getElementById("Hslide").setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:saturate(" + value + "%)");
}
function showValue(slideAmount1)
{
    var pic = $('effects').val();
    $('#pic').css('-webkit-filter', 'brightness('+slideAmount1+')');
    $('#range').val(slideAmount1);
    document.getElementById("Vslide").setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:saturate(" + value + "%)");
}
</script>
```

The problem: Whenever I slide and change the saturation AND then change the brightness, the image filter value resets before applying the second filter changes that i made. If there a way to to apply two filter to an image?

Comment: prefer slider in jqueryui. refer link http://jqueryui.com/slider/#multiple-vertical

Comment: You can't have two functions with the same name

Comment: this is hapening because you are saving the changes made by first slider. There are two ways to deal with it either you save your image just after slider 1 finish it works or store the changes made by sliders in cookies or sessions and applyy it to change event of sliders